# Create possible pairs irrespective of order in a indefinite set of values

Tags: java, compare, set

What i am trying to figure out is an algorithm that will create possible pairs irrespective of order in a indefinite set of values.

for example let's say the set is A,B,C,D,E

then possible sets are

AB
AC
AD
AE
BC
CD
DE

but... i also want pairs of more than 2 values.

for example

ABC
ABD
ABE
BCD
BCE

but also ABCD or ABCE. The problem here is that i want to make a method with input an array of Strings STring[] and the output would be a list of Strings in pair of 2,3.... up to number of values -1.

If anyone has a thought of a solution please help. :)

Comment: You didn't mention this, but I assume from your question that you would only want each item in the set to be used once, for instance in the set A,B,C,D,E: AAAA is not a valid pairing?

Comment: do you consider ABCDE an appropriate element in your set or not?

Comment: Why did you title this the way you did and list "compare" as a tag? Are you generating the powerset in order to test whether an particular string set is in it or not? If so, there may be more efficient hueristics to get that information.

Comment: hi,

thanks for your answer. Basically i have a large set of data that i have categorized. this data consists of persons and each person may have categories such as publications or place of birth or undergraduate studies. now each category may have one or more values. for example someone may have undergraduate studies from New York and Berlin. What i want is to select any field i wish (or all) from the thousands that exist of all persons in my databsase and try and mine any relationships between them. so if someone selects 5 fields to mine then i want the program to search for any combination

Answer (score 5):

It seems you want to construct a [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728972/finding-all-the-subsets-of-a-set) is essentially the same, look there for answers.

Comment: great! that is exactly what i was looking for. i just need to make a function in a thread to try and find any set from a given larger set of values! ::D

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the most computation-intensive things you could do. This will not scale well at all with an even remotely large set of data.

It's really not practical for indefinite sets. You could limit the pairs which can be generated, and therefore make this scale better.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to create is some kind of [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Algorithms) of your input's permutations.

Java's [iterator concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#Java) theoretically allows infinite sequences.

But what has your question to do with *comparing*?

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient, but a solution:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class PowersetTest {

public static void main(String [] args){
    Set<Set<String>> sets =  permute(Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e"));
    for (Set<String> item : sets){
        System.out.printf("Set: %s%n", item.toString());
    }
}
    static public <T> Set<Set<T>> permute (Collection<T> items){
      Set<Set<T>> result = new HashSet<Set<T>>();
      for (final T item : items){
        Set<T> subsetElements = filter(items, new Predicate<T>(){public boolean apply(T f){ return (f!=item);}});
        if (subsetElements.size() > 0) {
          result.addAll(permute(subsetElements));
        }
        Set<T> temp = new HashSet<T>();
        temp.addAll(items);
        result.add(temp);
      }
      return result;
    }

  static public <T> Set<T> filter(Collection<T> items, Predicate<T> filter){ 
    Set<T> result = new HashSet<T>();
    for (T item : items){ 
      if (filter.apply(item)) {
        result.add(item);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  public interface Predicate<T>{ public boolean apply(T item); }
}
```