# Powerset for large array size

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to find the sum of all subsets of a powerset for a large-sized array (up to 1500). I searched but was unable to find an efficient algorithm for this.

Example:

```
array=[1,2,3]
```

Answer:

```
{} -> 0,{1} -> 1,{2} -> 2,{3} -> 3,{1,2} -> 3,{1,3} -> 4,{2,3} -> 5,{1,2,3} -> 6
```

Is there an efficient way to do so?

Comment: C++,I mentioned in heading

Comment: Then why did you tag the question with C++ *and* C?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728972/finding-all-the-subsets-of-a-set, IMO your questions is kind of dup of it

Answer (score 1):

There are 2^n subsets of an array with n elements.

Each element will be present in exactly half of them.

Therefore the sum of all subsets will be the sum of all elements multiplied by 2<sup>n-1</sup>.

Comment: i want to find sum of each subset separately as in example..

Comment: @kvnt1102 There are going to be 2^1500 of these subsets, do you _really_ need them all separately?

Comment: there is a problem to find out number of the subsets whose modulo m is k

Comment: @kvnt1102 Try solving that problem by using dynamic programming where DP[i][k] gives the number of subsets of the first i elements of your array which have sum equal to k modulo m.