# How to call functions on a set<set<int>> container in c++?

Tags: c++, iterator, set

I am trying to insert values into a set < set > container in c++, I am using an iterator to iterate through the outer set, and then attempting to simply call the insert function on the iterator after dereferencing. this is the current code:

```
for ( set<set<int>>::iterator new_it=subsetTemp.begin();new_it!=subsetTemp.end();new_it++){
        (*new_it).insert( num );
    }
```

Throws error of:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set<int>::insert(const int&) const’
```

and:

```
 error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘std::set<int>::value_type&& {aka int&&}’ to lvalue of type ‘const int’
```

this is the full code:

```
set< set<int> > getAllSubsets(set<int> superset)
{
    set< set<int> > subset;
    set<int> empty;
    subset.insert( empty );

    for ( const int& supernum : superset){
        set< set<int> > subsetTemp = subset;  //making a copy of given 2-d set.

        for ( set<set<int>>::iterator new_it=subsetTemp.begin();new_it!=subsetTemp.end();new_it++){
            (*new_it).insert( supernum );   // adding set[i] element to each subset of subsetTemp. like adding {2}(in 2nd iteration  to {{},{1}} which gives {{2},{1,2}}.
        }

        for ( set<set<int>>::iterator new_it=subsetTemp.begin();new_it!=subsetTemp.end();new_it++){
            subset.insert( *new_it );  //now adding modified subsetTemp to original subset (before{{},{1}} , after{{},{1},{2},{1,2}}) 
        }
    }
    return subset;
}
```

the application is to get all subsets of a set - the function takes in a set e.g. {1,3,5}, and attempts to find all possible subsets of that set within a set e.g. { {1} , {1,3} , {3} .... {1,5} } , utilises the code from [Finding all the subsets of a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728972/finding-all-the-subsets-of-a-set)

Thanks

Comment: The elements of a `std::set` are `const`; you cannot modify them.  Thus you cannot insert into `*new_it` because it refers to an element in a `std::set<std::set<int>>`.

Answer (score 1):

The element of `set` can't be changed, think about this: On each change of the element, the order of the `set` may be changed(A `set` is an ordered container).

You may change the temporary container into a `vector`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
set<set<int>> getAllSubsets(set<int> superset) {
  set<set<int>> subset;
  set<int> empty;
  subset.insert(empty);

  for (int supernum : superset) {
    vector<set<int>> subsetTemp(
        subset.begin(), subset.end());  // making a copy of given 2-d set.

    for (auto new_it = subsetTemp.begin(); new_it != subsetTemp.end();
         new_it++) {
      new_it->insert(supernum);  // adding set[i] element to each subset of
                                 // subsetTemp. like adding {2}(in 2nd iteration
                                 // to {{},{1}} which gives {{2},{1,2}}.
    }

    for (auto new_it = subsetTemp.begin(); new_it != subsetTemp.end();
         new_it++) {
      subset.insert(
          *new_it);  // now adding modified subsetTemp to original subset
                     // (before{{},{1}} , after{{},{1},{2},{1,2}})
    }
  }
  return subset;
}
```

Or simpler with the range for, and `std::move` to avoid unnecessary copy.

```cpp
set<set<int>> getAllSubsets(const set<int>& superset) {
  set<set<int>> subset;
  set<int> empty;
  subset.insert(empty);

  for (int supernum : superset) {
    vector<set<int>> subsetTemp(subset.begin(), subset.end());
    for (auto& temp_inner_set : subsetTemp) {
      temp_inner_set.insert(supernum);
    }

    for (auto& temp_inner_set : subsetTemp) {
      subset.insert(std::move(temp_inner_set));
    }
  }
  return subset;
}
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a3bGW5nqd)